# Rails: Iterate through attributes with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a rails model with a large number of fields (112), for loading a configuration. I would like, in the edit and show forms, display only **if the field is already filled**. That is, if the field is **null** in the database then do not display it for edit.

There are two records - the main one is Batch and there is a 1:1 relationship to the Primer3Batch class. I'm trying to do an edit on the Primer3Batch class on the show action of Batch, **I'm not sure if this is a good idea or will even work.**

I have tried using the **attributes** method and am getting this error:

```
undefined method `attributes' for #<SimpleForm::FormBuilder
```

**batches_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @batch = Batch.find(params[:id])
  @primer3 = Primer3Batch.where(:batch_id => @batch.id)[0]

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @batch }
  end
end
```

**batches/show.html.erb**

```
<h1>Batch Details: <%= @batch.id %></h1>

<%= simple_form_for(@primer3) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <% f.attributes.each_attribute do |a| %>
      <% if a %><%# if a is not nil %>
        <%= f.input a %><%# send the field to the form %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

***EDIT***

Thank you **JSWorld** for pointing out the error of using the instance variable. I have corrected it and seem to have gotten further but it's still not quite right. This is the line changed - note **attributes.each** as **attributes.each_attribute** doesn't work.

```
<% @primer3.attributes.each do |a| %>
```

Now I am getting an error on the form fields:

```
undefined method `["id", 110]' for #<Primer3Batch:
```

I guess I need to somehow turn this :

```
a   ["id", 110]
```

into:

```
<%= f.input :id %>
```

*** EDIT 2 ***

Final code block based on **IIya Khokhryakov's** answer.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@primer3) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <% @primer3.attributes.each_pair do |name, value| %>
      <%= f.input name if value %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I've tried the above with form_for also and I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@primer3.attributes` is a Hash of the model's attributes and their values. So you can do something like this:

```
<% @primer3.attributes.each_pair do |name, value| %>
  <%= f.input name if value %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks IIya that's exactly what I was looking for. That's a really useful pattern. I'll update the question with the final code.

Answer (score 2):

I hope your intention is `@primer3.attributes` and not `f.attributes`. The error is because `f` is the form object and does not have `attributes` associated with it.